# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find shared library

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I am having libcommon.so in the /usr/local/lib and I am linking this library in my program.

> gcc -o test test_prog.c -L/usr/local/lib -llibcommon.so

and I have tried this too

> gcc -o test test_prog.c -L/usr/local/lib -llibcommon

It's giving

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibcommon.so
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

It is there:

```
$ locate libcommon.so
/usr/local/lib/libcommon.so
/usr/local/lib/libcommon.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libcommon.so.0.1.0
$
```

Comment: you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948521/building-error-using-cmake-cannot-find-lpthreads/52069326#52069326)

Answer (score 8):

When you use the `-l`, you specify just the 'basic' library name:

```
-lcommon
```

This will track down `libcommon.so` in some directory.

You told the compiler to try and find `liblibcommon.so.so` (and `liblibcommon.so`) and it probably couldn't...indeed, you wouldn't be asking the question if it could.

Some GNU programs build a library `libiberty.so` (or its equivalent), so the link lines using the library link with:

```
-liberty
```

(which is funny; GNU would really rather it was `+liberty`, but ... you can't fix everything).

Comment: i am getting this after changing according to you /usr/local/lib /libcommon.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Now you have a different problem.  The linker finds the library, but can't make sense of what is in it.  I suggest starting by running `file /usr/lib/libcommon.so /lib/libc.so` and looking to see if there's an obvious difference between the file types.  You may have to follow symlinks (so you may have to specify a different names in the `file` command line.  If there's a big difference, then you may have installed the wrong file(s) — or the system administrator may have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-lcommon` switch when you link `libcommon.so`

Answer (score 1):

try to export LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the directory where you have kept the so files .

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /pathofdirectorywheresofilesarekept